# MySQL Adding Slashes When I Don't Want Them

Tags: mysql, yahoo, quote

We are using Yahoo Web Hosting (not my choice) and the MySQL Database is acting weird. When I put in a simple query such as:

> update mytable set columnname = "new value" where id = 1;

it returns an error saying:

> ERROR: Unclosed quote
>
> STR: "
>
> SQL: update mytable set columnname = \"new value\" where id = 1;

I tried contacting Yahoo about it and they said they do not provide support for "Advanced Scripting", so that is why I am asking here.

Thank You.

**Updates:**

Single vs. Double Quotes does not make a difference

There is no way to connect to the database via MySQL Administrator, Yahoo has access blocked

I have found that magic_quotes_gpc is turned on, which could be causing the error, given that I am forced to use PHPMyAdmin to access the database - but I have no way to turn off magic_quotes_gpc.

Comment: Tch. 'Advanced scripting' my ass. Are you using some sort of database library or helper class? Is this done purely in MySQL, or is another language involved that generates the queries?

Comment: This is when I run the query directly is PHPMyAdmin and if I run a query via PHP. I have not tried connecting via Query Browser / MySQL Administrator.

Comment: Maybe try using single-quotes instead of double-quotes? The use of double-quotes for string literals is non-standard, and MySQL's support for it can be turned off via configuration. (Though this, admittedly, is not the error-message I'd expect to see.)

Comment: (By the way, I think the backslashes are probably just being added in the error-message, and not actually in the problematic SQL statement. I know I've seen error messages that replace non-ASCII characters with `\x...`-style escapes; changing `"` to `\"` could be along the same lines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is being escaped, probably happens when posting or something. Try this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET columnname = 'new value' WHERE id = 1;
```

In the old days I would guess `magic_quotes` or something might be causing this, but I'm assuming that's turned off.

Comment: Single vs Double Quotes makes no difference, did you change something else?